# How to format "du" output to display filesize only?

Tags: disk-usage, macos

This is how I get a file size in MacOS:

```
$ du -h "Anthem - Rush (Cover by Jewel Box).webm"          
 69M    Anthem - Rush (Cover by Jewel Box).webm
```

I want only **69M** in the output. **Anthem - Rush (Cover by Jewel Box).webm** is omitted. How to do that?

Comment: That's not the file's size, it's its disk usage. For the file's size, see `ls -l`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`du` reports the `d`isk `u`sage of files, not their (apparent) size.

The size of a file can be reported with `ls` and its `-l`/`-o`/`-g`/`-n` options (among other informations) or by various implementations of a `stat` utility with different and incompatible syntax or with the GNU implementation of `find` with its `-printf '%s\n'`.

The GNU implementation of `du` also has a `--apparent-size` for it to return the size instead of disk usage, however that can't be used for directories as for those types of files, `du` always adds the disk usage / size of all files referenced within.

So here, to get the size of a file after symlink resolution and with KMGTPE suffixes, on a GNU system, I'd do:

```
stat -Lc%s -- "$file" | numfmt --to=iec
```

Comment: OK, learn something new today: `numfmt --to=iec`. BTW On MacOS, `stat -Lc%s` isn't valid.`stat -f%z` works fine, though.

Comment: @anta40 or use zsh's stat built-in (predates both GNU and BSD stat). `zmodload zsh/stat; stat +size file`

Answer (score 3):

Just keep the first field. You can do this in various ways:

1. cut

   ```
   du -h "Anthem - Rush (Cover by Jewel Box).webm" | cut -f1
   ```
2. awk

   ```
   du -h "Anthem - Rush (Cover by Jewel Box).webm" | awk '{print $1}'
   ```
3. sed

   ```
   du -h "Anthem - Rush (Cover by Jewel Box).webm" | sed 's/[[:blank:]].*//'
   ```
4. Perl

   ```
   du -h "Anthem - Rush (Cover by Jewel Box).webm" | perl -pe 's/\s.*//'
   du -h "Anthem - Rush (Cover by Jewel Box).webm" | perl -lane 'print $F[0]'
   ```

Comment: Note that for an arbitrary file path (that may or may not contain newline characters), you'd want to make sure you skip the second and subsequent lines of the file path, so `sed 's/.../.../; q'` or `awk 'NR == 1 {print $1}'`, etc

Answer (score 0):

You can use sample `awk` command to do what you want:

```
du -h <filename>|awk '{print $1}'
```

Answer (score 0):

To expand a little on terdon's various ways of extracting the useful part of du's output, in some of my scripts I've needed to use different parts of the output from a program, but I don't want to run the program more than once to extract the different fields.  So I run the program once and capture it's full (raw, unfiltered) output into one variable, then use shell variable expansion to extract each field I need from that variable.

For example you could do this to remember the full output:

```
du_output_raw=$(du -h 'Anthem - Rush (Cover by Jewel Box).webm')
```

and then extract the first space-separated field for the file size:

```
f_size=${du_output_raw%% *)
```

The file's encoding is in the filename extension, extract the part after the last dot:

```
f_encoding=${du_output_raw##*.}
```

This is a good and bad example.  It's good because I've just extracted parts of the output that are delimited by different characters (one using space, the other using '.').  It's bad because I wouldn't really use the du output to extract the filename extension, I would use the filename that's already in another variable. But this shows the general idea.

I'm sure someone will point out that you can remember the output in an array variable for more automatic splitting into fields:

```
du_output=( $(du -h 'Anthem - Rush (Cover by Jewel Box).webm' )
```

or (using a bash feature that might not be in other shells):

```
read -a du_output < <(du -h 'Anthem - Rush (Cover by Jewel Box).webm')
```

and then use the array elements with the useful info:

```
f_size="${du_output[0]}"
f_encoding=${du_output[-1]##*.}
```